# forking git project for different OS

Tags: git, git-branch, git-submodules, branching-and-merging

I have an OSX app which I have build myself in python.  Like many OSX apps it has many (all?) of its dependencies within it.  eg...

```
./git_repo
└── mac (dir)
    ├── myapp.app (dir)
    │   ├── Frameworks (dir)
    │   ├───MacOS (dir)
    │   ├───Resources (dir)
    │   │   ├──main.py
    │   │   ├──lib1.py
    │   │   ├──lib2.py
            ├─img(dir)
```

The directory structure is much larger than this, with many files in each dir, but you get the idea

My first fork will be for Linux, in which I need main.py,lib1.py,lib2.py and the img dir.  I need nothing else in the Resources dir, or any other dir.  I will also be adding Linux specific files which are not require for mac.  The overall dir structure will be much more flat than the mac structure.

After that I will be forking for Windows, with the files I've listed for Linux, and some Windows specific files not required for mac/linux.

I have read the similar threads here but I can't visualize how the overall directory structure will work.
I see a couple of options.

1. Use separate git branches and merge/cherry-pick changes in when required (this may be difficult as the directory structure of all 3 will be completely different
2. Use git submodules - have been reading up about this, but not sure which components I should make submodules - the common items, or the extras?
3. use separate repositories - not sure if this is any different to branches

Ultimately I just need to track changes for those main files for all 3 OSs whilst keeping the changes separate, and without having to take huge steps when working on a particular OS/branch (eg make file etc)

What is the best way of achieving this?
Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1):

If the source files are all or mostly the same across platforms, there's no reason you should be mantaining separate branches, forks or submodules to coerce them into a different structure.

The best way to go about this would be to structure your project as a standard setuptools/distutils project with a `setup.py`. Then, use [the py2app extension](http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html#abstract) to build your OS X application bundle, and [the py2exe extension](http://www.py2exe.org/) to build your Windows executables.

The second-best way would be to structure your project in a way that makes sense to you, and have build scripts that copy the appropriate files into place. For instance, have a `src/` folder with all your Python sources, a `build/` folder that's ignored by Git, and a `build-mac.sh` that creates an application bundle inside `build/` and copies your Python source files into place.

Bottom line is, keep all your code in one place, then have a way to automatically copy it into the appropriate structure once you get around to actually building redistributable binaries. It's going to be a hell of a lot easier running one script for each platform every release than it is keeping two or three otherwise-identical repos in sync all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `git-submodule` and make the common parts submodules, and link them in the appropriate platform branches.